# Linq to Entity to return a record from left table and 0 or 1 of right table using Method Syntax?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to return a record from my main table with a join to a secondary table that may or may not return a record. I need to do this using Method Syntax if at all possible.

My current query is

```
 Organizations.Where(a=>a.OrganizationId==10033)
        .Join(Addresses, org => org.ClientId, addy => addy.ClientId, (org, addy) => new { org, addy })
        .Join(Contacts, o => o.org.OwnerClientId, c => c.ClientId, (o, c) => new { o, c })
        .Select(a => new Establishment
        {
            Name = a.o.org.Name,
            City = a.o.addy.PhysicalAddressCity,
            State = a.o.addy.PhysicalAddressState,
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(a.o.org.OrganizationId),
            AddressLine = a.o.addy.PhysicalAddressLine,
            ZipCode = a.o.addy.PhysicalFullPostal,
            AssignedInspector = "Jacques Clouseau",
            ManagerName = a.c.LastName
            }).FirstOrDefault()
```

This returns the correct information if there is a matching record in the contact table but I need it to return the Org and Address even if there is no Contact.

Is this possible using Method Syntax?

*****Additional note:

Forgot to mention this is using EF Core 3.0

Comment: Use navigation properties. Don't join.

Comment: This is a set of legacy tables that are in very rough shape regarding PK & FKs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GroupJoin:

```
Organizations.Where(a=>a.OrganizationId==10033)
        .Join(Addresses, org => org.ClientId, addy => addy.ClientId, (org, addy) => new { org, addy })
        .GroupJoin(Contacts, o => o.org.OwnerClientId, c => c.ClientId, (o, contact) => new { o, c = contact.FirstOrDefault() })
        .Select(a => new Establishment
        {
            Name = a.o.org.Name,
            City = a.o.addy.PhysicalAddressCity,
            State = a.o.addy.PhysicalAddressState,
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(a.o.org.OrganizationId),
            AddressLine = a.o.addy.PhysicalAddressLine,
            ZipCode = a.o.addy.PhysicalFullPostal,
            AssignedInspector = "Jacques Clouseau",
            ManagerName = a.c.LastName
            }).FirstOrDefault()
```